# как получить путь к папке asset из контроллера yii2?

Tags: yii2

Есть класс MenuGenerator. По нажатию на кнопку он генерирует html код, который записывает в файл и отдаёт его браузеру как чистый html. Некоторые рессурсы, ссылки на которые мне надо получить, публикуются в assets. Используется тема с такой структурой папок:

- frontend
- - themes
- - - neat
- - - - views
- - - - - layouts
- - - - - site
- - - - web
- - web
- - - assets <-- папка, в которую публикуются ресурсы

В этой ситуации у меня нет объекта `View`, поэтому, чтоб получить ссылку на файл ресурса в указанной папке я не могу использовать

```
$this->theme->getUrl('img/promo/actuality.jpg')
```

не могу юзать

```
$this->assetManager->getBundle(MyAsset::className());
```

не могу

```
MyAsset::register($this);
```

также не могу обратиться к методу getAssetUrl из AssetManager.

Как в этой ситуации получить ссылку на папку assets типа frontend/web/assets/328e8b1a ?

Comment: `Yii::getAlias('@frontend') . '/web/assets/...';`

Comment: Это понятно... а хеш?

Comment: А  html генерируется с помощью  view?

Comment: я не срвсем понял вопрос, но скорее всего нет

Comment: Получается так, что в класс MenuGenerator надо передать этот хеш, до генерации файла.

Comment: @Oughtem получается какая-то ерунда, зачем сохранять в assets сгенерированный по какой-то кнопке html? Если папка assets будет очищена (например при новой сборке дженкинсом или куча других вариантов, все содержимое assets не просто так в гитигноре находится), как этот html перегенерируется у вас?

Answer (score 1):

Класс View доступен на уровне Application, потому достучаться до вьюхи можно по сути с любого места.
Как вариант, если нужно достать из контроллера путь, можно например а afterAction обратиться к зарегестрированным бандлам:

```
$assetManager = $this->view->assetManager;
$sameAssetManager = Yii::$app->view->assetManager;
```

Ну или еще проще, обратиться напрямую к менеджеру ассетов:

```
$stillAssetManager = Yii::$app->assetManager;
```

А оттуда список бандлов

```
$registered = $assetManager->bundles
$registered = $assetManager->getBundle($registeredClassName)
```

У каждого ассета можно будет взять путь (физический или урл)

```
$registered->basePath
$registered->baseUrl
```

Answer (score 0):

Сам наткнулся на эту проблему, Нужно было подтянуть картинку из ассета. Решение оказалось на поверхности.

Yii в момент публикации ассета меняет baseUrl на фактический, т.е. можно делать вот так

```
<?php
$myAssetBundle = MyAsset::register($this);
?>
<img src="<?= $myAssetBundle->baseUrl ?>/my-image.png">
```